# Change .ejs extension to .html using Parse.com Express.js

Tags: node.js, express, parse-platform, ejs

How would I go about using .html extensions on my view files instead of .ejs when using Parse.com's Express.js?

I changed the EJS delimiters to `<?` and `?>` because I'm used to them from PHP. That worked fine, but I can't seem to change the file extension for my view files:

I've tried the following:

```
var express = require('express');
var ejs = require('ejs');
var app = express();

ejs.open = '<?';
ejs.close = '?>';

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.engine('.html', ejs.renderFile);
app.set('views', 'cloud/views'); app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('Test', { message: 'Hello Express!' });
});

app.listen();
```

And I get an internal server error.

I've also tried eliminating this line with the same result:

`app.set('view engine', 'ejs');`

Comment: I'm not sure who down voted this question, but its a good question. I just didn't something similar with handlebars and changed all the .handlebars/.hbs files to .html lemme see if i can get something working for you.

Comment: I posted an answer for you, if it works, make it as correct, if not tell me so I can help!

Comment: Hi Jemilol, I've actually already tried that and it didn't work. I've abandoned the idea of using Parse.com to host my Express project. It's a very weird, restricted environment. And they're unclear as to what you can and cannot do with your 'server'. I opted to spin up my own Node/Express server at Digital Ocean, which is awesome.

Comment: If you haven't already, check out sails.js and loopback.js, good frameworks built off of express.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.engine('html', ejs.renderFile);
```

So I did app.set to html and app.engine to html and it was working for me.

Comment: Changed my mind to make this the correct answer. However, I never did get this working with Parse.com, even though this is the correct syntax to achieve this using Express.js.

Answer (score 1):

this way works too:

```
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.engine('html',require('ejs').renderFile);
```

someone knows any problem using this way?

Comment: It's the same. The accepted answer is assuming that `var ejs = require('ejs')` was specified earlier.