# EJS does not render value returned from res.render

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I'm getting the page redirects correctly however when I'm going to list this result in the front-end the value is not shown just the command of the EJS in my front-end view.[image]

I've tried to pass the output value in several different ways but none worked...

This my root files.

[image]

My index.js

```
var http = require('http');
var express    = require('express'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    ejs = require('ejs'),
    nunjucks   = require('nunjucks'),
    path = require('path'),
    mysql      = require('mysql'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    methodOverride = require('method-override'),
    logger = require('morgan');
var errorHandler = require('errorhandler');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

import config from "./config/config";
import mongodb from "./config/mongodb";
import passport from "./config/passport";
import * as setup from "./middleware/setup";

import app from "./config/express";
import routes from "./routes";

import User from './models/User';

export function start() {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    mongodb().then((db) => {

      let server = http.createServer(app);

      // save references
      app.db = db;
      app.server = server;
      app.config = config;

      // init passport
      passport(app);

      // register setup check middleware
      app.use(setup.check);

      // setup routes
      routes(app);

      // start server
      app.server.listen(config.server.port, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        resolve(app);
      });
    }, reject);
  });
};

app.set('views', __dirname + '/templates');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

var api = express.Router();
app.use('/', api);

api.get('/test-ejs', function (req, res) {
  res.render('test.html', { title: 'Return sucess!' });
});

api.get("/templates",function(req, res){
  var path = __dirname + '/templates/';
  res.sendFile(path + "index.html");
});
```

My HTML template test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html lang="en">  
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test EJS</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- styles -->
    <link href="stylesheets/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
  <body>
    <%= title %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thank for helping me! xD

Comment: Please set view engine `app.set('view engine', 'html');`.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [Change .ejs extension to .html using Parse.com Express.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21922854/change-ejs-extension-to-html-using-parse-com-express-js)

Answer (score 0):

You are using .html file for rendering the data but in your app.js you have defined it as .ejs under app.engine line.

So either you have change the .html file type to .ejs or you have to replace your app.engine line with this

```
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```